# Construct std::string from multiple char arrays using initializer list

Tags: c++, string, constructor, initializer-list

Just a reminder, I am not asking for a solution to solving this problem, but rather an explanation of a behaviour. Constructing an instance of `std::string` by providing an initializer-list with multiple C style strings does not result in a compilation error, but does in a runtime error. Code is as follows:

```
std::string s{"abc", "bcd"};
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Signature of constructor is `string (initializer_list<char> il);`. How does it treat (tries to treat) these char arrays exactly?

Error is as follows:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_create
[1]    89429 IOT instruction (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

Comment: I imagine that your string literals are converted to pointers and you are invoking the constructor that takes two input iterators. The two pointers are not a valid iterator range so you get an error.

Comment: @john Aren't I explicitly invoking the initializer_list constructor when I pass arguments in curly braces?

Comment: @ZlatanRadovanovic You are, but the initializer list constructor for `std::string` takes a `std::initializer_list<char>`, while `{"abc", "bcd"}` would be a `sdtd::initializer_list<const char*>` so you are not using strings initializer list constructor but instead are getting its iterator pair constructor.

Answer (score 4):

The constructor which takes an `std::initializer_list<char>` can only be used to create a string from multiple characters, not from multiple other strings. For example:

```cpp
std::string s{'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
```

Note that list initialization will *not only* call constructors that accept `std::initializer_list`, it can also call other constructors.
Only *if* a constructor taking `std::initializer_list` can be called with list initialization, it *always* wins in overload resolution (with the exception of an empty list, which is value initialization).

In this case, it can't be used, so another constructor is called.
You're getting an error because of this constructor:

```cpp
template< class InputIt >
basic_string(InputIt first, InputIt last,
             const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

String literals `"abc"` and `"bcd"` can be used as iterators, and if `"bcd" < "abc"` (pointer comparison), then the computed size of the range `"bcd" - "abc"` is negative, or in the quintillions of bytes after conversion to `std::size_t`, which might be slightly too large for your system. As a result, `std::length_error` is thrown.

##### Solution

To construct a string from one or multiple strings, you could do:

```cpp
auto s = std::string("abc") + "bcd";
// or
using namespace std::string_literals;
auto s = "abc"s + "bcd"s;
```

---

See also: [`std::string` constructors on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)